# Push vs polling for result

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have some requests which can take upto 2 minutes to process. These requests are sent from the Android app to the server. The request timeout for my server is fixed (i.e. 30 seconds). So I will have to cache the request /result at the server and when the client comes again with the same request, I can just return the cached result. I can do this in 2 ways

- The client will hit the server with the request and the server will block the client and wait for the result to come back. If it does, then it will return the result. Else the client will get a timeout result. The client will then try again (this time the server won't do the processing again, it will poll the cache every 1 second to see if the result was updated from the previous request). In the retry also, the client would be blocked for 30 seconds or when the server gets the result.
- The client hits the server with the request and the server returns an empty response. Then when the server has completed the task, the server sends a GCM ping to the client. When the client receives the ping, it makes the request again and gets the result back.

I know that GCM ping would be better in case that the time duration of getting the result was large (>30 minutes) because the other solution would require unnecessary polling. But what about when the request can take at max 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

How about immediately returning an id (instead of empty response), then using the id when polling. This way you can put the results in a different place if you don't want to load your application server with polling requests. Poll less frequently. 
GCM is not guaranteed to deliver.